# Django - AWS S3 Bucket - Showing images/css but not javascript/webfont and file uploads

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am making a portfolio website using django. Everything is working well on my local machine. I decided to use AWS S3 buckets to host my static files. After following a few tutorials I was able to make a bucket and link my account over. The issue I have now is that the images and css loads fine on my website, however the webfonts and javascript files seem to not work. I also have a link to download my resume, but that does not work. When clicking on the files it gives me an error of:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>resume.pdf</Key>
<RequestId>xxx</RequestId>
<HostId>xxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

Interestingly the url in the browser seems to be attempting to pull from AWS.

When I go into the S3 bucket I see all files available. When opening images on my website they are properly pulling from AWS.

My CORS is set to:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

And settings.py is:

```
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2' # Your region name
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_VERSION = 's3v4'
AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'xxx'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Is there something I have missed that wont let my js/webfonts/files from working on my site?

Comment: Sounds like a pathing issue perhaps. Check the URLs your web page fetches for CSS that work compared to JS that don't. Then compare how you have your static assets organized.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the solution. It looks like S3 was not giving bucket access. I edited the bucket policy on AWS S3 to the below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Replace the bucketname with your actualy bucketname. Hope this helps anyone who might run into this issue.

Comment: Does this explain how your web page was able to load CSS but not JS?